# Как создать страницу с дизайном отличным от других?

Tags: joomla

Не могу найти информации как создать страницу с особым отличным от других страниц сайта дизайном. Случаем не альтернативный макет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Установить нужный шаблон
2. Перейти в Расширения - Шаблоны - Стили и открыть нужный стиль шаблона
3. Вкладка Привязка к меню. Тут можно привязать нужный шаблон к необходимой странице.